# Как можно упростить этот код JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
function change() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value,
        input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value,
        sum = 50;

        if (input1 < 0){
          document.getElementById('input1').classList.add('error-input');
        }
        else if (input2 < 0){
          document.getElementById('input2').classList.add('error-input');
        }
        else{
          document.getElementById("summ").value = (input1 * input2)* sum;
          document.getElementById('input1').classList.remove('error-input');
          document.getElementById('input2').classList.remove('error-input');
        }

  }
```

Comment: галку можно поставить только на один ответ.

Comment: и это одинаковые ответы у нас с @Yuri, без разницы какой выберите

Comment: Спасибо. Понял)

Comment: Вот ещё вопрос. А что такое summ, на который вы домножаете? Посмотрел свой код ещё раз -- сложилось двоякое впечатление: толи у вас summ не нужно вообще (выкинуть), толи это какой-то домножающий коэффициент. Поясните.

Comment: Summ это Id для input где у меня отображается ответ произведения, а sum это неизменяемое число

Comment: Тогда бы вы написали `document.getElementById(sum).value = (input1 * input2);`

Comment: Можно даже сказать константа равная 50 :)

Comment: Обновил оба варианта ответа с учётом ваших уточнений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код неплохой, но единственное, что я сделал бы:

```
function change() {
  var i1 = document.getElementById("input1"),
      i2 = document.getElementById("input2"),
      sum = 50;

  if (i1.value < 0){
    i1.classList.add('error-input');
  }else if (i2.value < 0){
    i2.classList.add('error-input');
  }else{
    document.getElementById("summ").value = (i1.value * i2.value)* sum;
    i1.classList.remove('error-input');
    i2.classList.remove('error-input');
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный сайт))))

Comment: @BeksultanNurkulov если ответ вам понравился, увеличьте счетчик слева у ответа, а если считаете его правильным, помечайте его как правильный ответ.

Comment: Был код может не самый эффективный, но рабочий. Теперь - код с ошибками.

Comment: @Igor и у меня была точно такая же ошибка: не заметил в суммировании. ))

Comment: Нет все правильно. Испытал. Спасибо, вроде в i1.value  была ошибка

Answer (score 2):

Ну держи. Самое короткое что смог придуматью Прошу заметить, что весь твой код поместился в одну строчку, буквально в несколько слов.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" ng-model='input1' placeholder='input1'>
     <input type="text" ng-model='input2' placeholder='input2'>
     <p>input1*input2*50 = {{  input2 ?  +input1*+input2*50 : input1 ? 'Введите число в input2!' : 'Введите число в input1!'}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно заполнить input2 и оставить пустым input1, не работает ваш однострочник :) Хотя чинится это наверно легко

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
function change() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1"),
        input2 = document.getElementById("input2"),
        sum = 50;

    if (input1.value < 0) {
        input1.classList.add('error-input');
    }
    else if (input2.value < 0) {
        input2.classList.add('error-input');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("summ").value = (input1.value * input2.value) * sum;
        input1.classList.remove('error-input');
        input2.classList.remove('error-input');
    }
}
```

Посмотрите, у вас везде используется однотипные конструкции вида `document.getElementById("input1")` - и это можно вынести в переменные -- улучшается читаемость кода, т.к. строки короче и проще понимать.

В остальном, как по мне улучшать особо нечего. Разве что кардинально менять скрипт, раздробив его на отдельные функции, что-то типа:

```
function change() {
    var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
    var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
    var koeff = 50;

    check_input(input1);
    check_input(input2);

    if (input1.value > 0 && input2.value > 0) {
        document.getElementById("summ").value = (input1.value * input2.value) * koeff;
    }
}

function check_input(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) {
        input.classList.add('error-input');
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('error-input');
    }
}
```

PS Непонятно, что за домножение на 50 идёт. Если это какой-то коэффициент -- его так и нужно называть. Если он не нужен -- тогда его нужно совсем выпилить.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручил!))